# What is the best way to extract load average float values from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point

If I have a string such as

"17:31:51 up 134 days, 11:26,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.15, 0.10"

what is the best way to extract just the x3 load average values at the end? I have written a regexp that does this but is this the most efficient / fastest method?

```
>>> s = "17:31:51 up 134 days, 11:26,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.15, 0.10"
>>> print re.findall(r"([0-9]\.\d+)", s)
['0.22', '0.15', '0.10']
```

Comment: You shouldn't worry about regular expression optimization. The call to os.system('uptime') you seem to use takes about 1000 times longer than the call to re.findall. http://hans.gerwitz.com/2004/08/12/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
# s is the string to parse
loadavg = [float(x) for x in s.rsplit('load average: ', 1)[1].split(', ')]
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the same information in `/proc/loadavg` special file, so you can do:

```
>>> open("/proc/loadavg").readline().split(" ")[:3]
```

Comment: Couldn't be uptime output also different?

Answer (score 4):

Or if you are actually looking for the load averages then in Python 2.3+ you have:

```
import os
os.getloadavg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way seems fine. If you want to avoid regexps you could do something like

```
>>> print s.split(': ')[1].split(', ')
['0.22', '0.15', '0.10']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regex, definitely.  You could perhaps increase efficiency a bit by first calling `s.find('load average')` and starting the regexp match from that position instead of at the beginning of the string (which is the default).

Comment: Actually, I like Adam's way better.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is the way. But maybe more robustly:

```
re.search(r"load average: (\d+.\d\d), (\d+.\d\d), (\d+.\d\d)$", s).groups()
```

Unless you're doing this really often in a tight loop or some such you needn't worry about performance. Clarity is what's most important. And there I'd say this regexp is hard to beat.

Comment: Think about it as a format string. Clear as clear can be, no?